# How do you ensure a UIView to be frontmost?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have UILabels animating on my mainView and I want to have a custom UIView pop onto the main view when a button is pressed. The labels animating in the background continue to animate and the problem that I'm having is that the labels animate on top of my custom UIView.

Does anyone know how I can ensure that my custom UIView is the front-most view so that the UILabels animate behind it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to look at

```
- (void)bringSubviewToFront:(UIView *)view
```

in the parent view.

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation UIView (moveToFront)

- (void) moveToFront {  [[self superview] bringSubviewToFront:self]; }

@end
```